# cocos2d - how to add a particle system to a scene

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, particles

I can't find any documentation on how to add a particle system created with Particle Designer to a scene.

All the programming guide says is this:

```
id particleSystem = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"MyParticle.plist"];
```

ok. then what? `[self addChild:particleSystem];` ?

Also, there's this problem:

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "CCParticleSystemQuad.h"
error: CCParticleSystemQuad.h: No such file or directory
```

Comment: If I do that instead, CCParticleSystemQuad *particleSystem; throws this error: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'CCParticleSystemQuad' with no type

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try using a `CCParticleSystem*` pointer just to see if that works any differently for you.  Here's a sample from one of the games I'm working on...

```
CCParticleSystem* particle_system = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"myEffect.plist"];
[my_node addChild:particle_system];

particle_system.position = ccp(xpos, ypos);
[particle_system resetSystem];
```

This is working great for me using 0.99.5.  You should definitely have the `particleWithFile` function in the Cocos2D implementation you are using provided you are using 0.99.5.

Answer (score 0):

the partacle system .h should already be in your project when you load it.

the book I'm using initializes the partacle system as

```
CCParticleSystemQuad* system = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:"blah.png"];
[self addChild:system z:1 tag:1];
```

it doesn't go into any detail other than that for initializing Particle system quads.

Comment: what imports do you have in the .h file? When I try your code I get this: error: 'CCParticleSystemQuad' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Are you using cocos2d 0.99.5 or are you using cocos2d 0.99.4?

Comment: Change it to CCQuadParticleSystem* and tell me if you get an error.

Comment: I don't get the compile error, but at runtime I get this: +[CCQuadParticleSystem particleWithFile:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xe9268

Comment: in fact, a search for "particleWithFile" in the entire project comes up empty. Did Cocos2d just decide to drop this unannounced?

Comment: No. If you didnt' get the compiler error when you changed the name, then you're still using 0.99.4 or earlier somewhere in your project.

Comment: I have never installed 0.99.4. 0.99.5 was my first install.

Comment: Do you have the templates installed? All my cocos2d apps were using the templates and when I just checked the cocos2d.h file CCParticleSystemQuad was included.

Comment: hmm... there is no method called particleWith file.. Mine is 99.5 as well.. try the function -(void) setTexture:(CCTexture2D *)texture withRect:(CGRect)rect;

Answer (score 0):

if your using cocos2d-iphone-0.99.5

you have to import "CCParticleSystemPoint.h"

and check below linezs also.

refer this word"ARCH_OPTIMAL_PARTICLE_SYSTEM " in your cocos2d libraries "ccparticleexamples.h"

hope this helps you.